# PuTTy connection time-out? (Ubuntu Server 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, ssh, iptables

I am trying to use PuTTy to manage my Ubuntu 14.04 Server. I am clearly doing something wrong with my SSH setup. Perhaps it has to do with my firewall rules?

Here are my rules in iptables:

[image]

What do I need to do so that I can perform networking duties with PuTTy, and get the ball rolling? I greatly appreciate any pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to reach the box from the internet? What's the set up like? Is the server behind router/NAT? Do you have a static public IP?

Comment: @meccooll A bit of clarity: I am connecting from PuTTy on a windows machine that is running Virtual Box. The Ubuntu Server (14.04) is running on the Virtual Box VM on the same device that I am running the PuTTy client on. In Virtual Box, the network setting under my Adapter 1 is bridged. Nothing is being handled over the internet as far as I know. Currently it is all on the same network.

When I do ifconfig, the IPv4 is 10.0.2.15

Comment: So Windows is the host OS,  and Ubuntu is the Vbox guest OS. How are the IPs assigned, is there a router on that interface that hands out IPs? What's windows host's IP/subnet and guest's subnet? Can you ping guest IP 10.0.2.15 from host (Windows)?

Comment: @meccooll Doing ipconfig on the windows host, the IP and subnet are 192.168.0.37 and 255.255.255.0, respectively. Also in the windows cmd, the ipv4 of the virtual box host-only network is 192.168.56.1

When I execute ip a on the command line, the ip is the 10.0.2.15 as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm no Vbox expert, but i think if you want Adapter 1 bridged then host-only network shouldn't matter. Make sure that Vbox its bridged to the correct interface (the one on 192.168.0.37 and NOT host-only network). If you want it bridged then it should be on the same subnet as your windows 192.168.0.37 subnet 255.255.255.0 network. If your Windows box gets it's IP automatically, then make sure your guest Ubuntu is also set to automatic, if not pick a free IP in 192.168.0.1-254 range and statically assign it to your guest Ubuntu (instead of setting it to 10.0.2.15)